# How to define new route for an Area folder that contains many razor pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Is there any easy way the define new routes for an area folder that contains many razor pages?

In mvc pattern we can define new route easily like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "auth",
   template: "auth/{action}",
   defaults: new { area = "Identity", controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
);
```

but I can't define new route in Startup.cs file for a folder that has many razor pages. 
Should I use conventions?

Answer (score 0):

For Area Razor Pages, there is no need to define convention routes.

Follow the URL `https://localhost:44353/areaname/razorpagename` to access the razor page.

eg, if you have Areas Folder like

[image]

Access this `Areas/Test/Pages/Index` by `https://localhost:44353/test/index`

Comment: Thank you @tao-zhou , actually I want to "rewrite" the default razor pages routes to new simple routes! How can I rewrite a folder routes